# Wants to create a new instance of books instead of update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

What I want is to create a profile pages, where i can view the previous book field and if the customer change the text then it would create a new books.

I have the following models with has_many relationship

```
Customer -- ID, First, Last, Email
Book -- ID, Description
Book_Managers -- ID, Customer_id, Book_id, Visible
```

Right now what i have is a customer edit which allow me to see multiple form by rendering from  many more models like books, phones, etc...

Here my customer Controller

```
def edit
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  if @customer.books.any?
    @book = @customer.books.order("created_at DESC").first
  else
    @book = @customer.books.build
  end
end
```

What i would like to see is if i created a new instance when going to book form i should see the last and able to modify "The JavaScript Bible" to something "The Java Bible" and it would not update it but just create a new version. Right now when going to the form book i see nothing. And if i do for some odd reason it was only allowing me to update.

```
 class BooksController < ApplicationController
   def create
     @book = current_customer.books.build(params[:book])
     if @book.save
       flash[:success] = "Book Created"
       redirect_to root_url
     else
       render 'customer/edit'
     end
   end

   def index
     @books = Book.all
   end

   def destroy
     @book.destroy
     redirect_to root_url
   end
 end
```

ADDED THIS

```
def update
 @book = current_customer.books.build(params[:book])
 if @book.save
   flash[:success] = "Book Updated"
   redirect_to root_url
 else
   render 'customer/edit'
 end
```

end

To my book controller, the only problem right now is my association, i can't seem to find any book with the current customer. is there somethign wrong with my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
def update
  params = params[:book].merge(:previous_version => params[:id])
  @book = current_customer.books.create(params[:book])
end
```

It will create a new book on each update. The last version will be the book without "previous_version".

Answer (score 1):

There is some gems for versioning. This that : https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Versioning

Comment: I am using it also to allow the customer to show to friend the content or not. So i cant use this hence i need my second model